# Is JAI really that usefull for raster images on Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, raster, geotiff-tiff, jvm, jai

I've been going back and forth with JAI for quite a while by now. I've never been really impressed with it to be honest. Is it really all that jazz that I hear people talk about?

The problem with JAI is that I'm stuck with a 32bit JVM, thus not fully utilizing the abundance of RAM that I have.

Has anyone done any head-to-head comparisons between 32bit JVM + JAI vs. 64bit JVM?

I have a Geoserver instance with 10k+ geotiff images, and only these geotiff images.
Which one of these setups would give me the best performace in your opinion?

JVM 32 bits
Native JAI installed
-Xmn1000m
-Xms1400m
-Xmx1400m
(among others)

JVM 64 bits
No native JAI
-Xmn2g
-Xms10g
-Xmx10g
-d64
(among others)

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: please read http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gs_steroids_sgiannec_foss4g2011.pdf

Comment: JVM 64 bit will not give more performance UNLESS you use all the cpu cores.. I have just tested it and I found that native 32 bit JAI exes are faster than Java mode of JAI in 64 bit JVM...

Comment: native mode gave me 45 seconds and java mode with 64 bit gave me 65 seconds in my project....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former should give you better performance, GeoServer is structured to minimize the use of memory and has no source data caches, so giving it more memory (past a certain point) does not really make it faster, just allows it to serve more requests in parallel... slower :-) 
The thing is, past 2x or 4x the number of CPUs the overall throughput will stop increasing anyways, so better just lock it down with control-flow instead.

If the OS has a good file system handling, it will make use of the extra memory it has to perform in memory caching of the most used files, and that's going to be a good boost too.